# What Design pattern for list of choices , when user select choice

Tags: design-patterns

I have an application where the user selects Initial choice and this choice will present another set of choices, each choice can invoke the flow of the application of present another list of choices.

For example:

```
app: what is you name ?
user: poko
app: what is your profession?
  1.programmer 
  2.Lawyer
  3.blacksmith
user: 2
app: what total income per year 
  1. above 100$
  2. above 200$
user: 2 
in the application:
app invokes layer handler with handling income above 200 $
```

What will be the best design pattern for such flow?

Comment: Does the next question depend on the concrete current answer? I mean If the user chose "above 100$" or "above 200$" then he'll see varied questions?

Comment: this can be also option , this is high level example , i need to see which pattern i can set

Comment: Every choice is a branch here. so It sounds like a decision tree example to me.

Comment: As pointed in the answer below, Its like having a class Option which is composed of a list of Options. Hence design can be based on `Composite` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As said @Roman it's a data structure. You should choose a data structure for the flow and after it, you should choose a method to represent this data structure into the application.  For example, if this data structure is a tree you can use [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to represent it. For example (I don't know what programming language is used you, therefore, I used PHP):

```
class Answer
{

   /**
    * @var string The text of the answer which will be shown to the user
    */
   public $text;

   /**
    * @var Question The question which will be shown to the user if the current answer was chosen
    */
   public $nextQuestion;

}

class Question
{

   /**
    * @var string The text of the question which will be shown to the user
    */
   public $text;

   /**
    * @var Answer[] List of answers by the question 
    */
   public $answers = [];

   /**
    * Choice of answer and getting the next question
    *
    * @param string $value The text of the answer
    * @return Questio The next question
    */
   public function chooseAnswer(string $value) : Question
   {
       foreach($this->answers as $answer) {
           if ($answer === $value) {
               return $answer->nextQuestion;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Design Pattern

> What will be the best design pattern for such flow?

There is not a single pattern for a problem.

Additional a design pattern doesn't solve a problem. Instead, it helps you to structure your code base. With other words: You do not need a design pattern to solve this problem, but you can use one or *more* to structure your code.

## Data Structure

Instead of a design pattern, you have data structures which can boost an algorithm. For an algorithmic problem, there is always an applicable data structure.

Your problem is a flow. This sounds like a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) witch you can traversal. The vertices could be an object that holds information about the question and the choices and the edges are the answers.